# How can I put a custom field as the link of a button shortcode?

Tags: php, custom-field, loop, shortcode, page-template

I have been working on a custom page template, and cannot seem to figure out how to have a custom field for URL's as the link for a button in the loop.

Here is my code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[standout-css3-button href='<?php
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'church-website-url', true); ?>']Church
website[/standout-css3-button]"); ?>
```

Does anyone know of some way to make this idea work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with shortcode but with your code - you can't nest  blocks ;)

This should work just fine, I guess:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[standout-css3-button href='". get_post_meta($post->ID, 'church-website-url', true) ."']Church website[/standout-css3-button]"); ?>
```